# Storing co-ordinate points in a listbox?

Tags: vb.net, listbox, coordinates

I have been trying to store several co-ordinate points in my `list box`.

When i click on any point on my form, the `X` and `Y` coordinates should be stored in a `listbox`. I need at least 10 of such points. I am able to do only do one at a time. Once, I click the next point, it replaces the first coordinate with the new coordinate.

I also want to attach some attributes to each point, say, Co-ordinate `X`,`Y` has a cost of $10. But my main challenge is getting all these co-ordinates out first.

Please advise how to go about this!

Comment: What code have you got so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom class which can hold the required data. Then use a `BindingList(Of T)` as the datasource for your `ListBox`.

Here is an example:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()
        Me.InitializeComponent()
        Me.list = New BindingList(Of ClickInfo)
        Me.ListBox1.DataSource = Me.list
        Me.ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Location"
    End Sub

    Private Sub _MybaseClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Click
        Me.list.Insert(0, New ClickInfo() With {.Location = Me.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition), .Cost = 1234})
    End Sub

    Private Class ClickInfo
        Public Property Location() As Point
        Public Property Cost() As Decimal
    End Class

    Private ReadOnly list As BindingList(Of ClickInfo)

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the coordinates of the point where the mouse is clicked using the onClick event of the Windows form. You can add this point to a collection (preferably an array as the size is fixed for just storing the 10 coordinates). Then you can add your coordinates to the array at a particular index.

While incrementing the index from 0-9, if the index reaches 9 change it to 0 and continue your incremental loop for storing N number of coordinate points in your array and replacing the old ones with the new ones.

For attaching an attribute to each coordinate you can use an array of

```
KeyValuePair(Of Point, Double)(10)
```

Here you can store the coordinate point as Key and its cost as the value.

Answer (score 0):

## Code And Example

```
Private Sub Form1_Click () Handles Mybase.Click   
      Me.Cursor = New Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle)
      Listbox1.Items.Add (Cursor.Position.X)
      Listbox2.Items.Add (Cursor.Position.Y)
End Sub
```

Or Alternatively,

```
Public Declare Auto Function GetCursorPos Lib "User32.dll" (ByRef lpPoint As Point) As Integer
Dim mousepos As Point
' This stores the cordinates of the mouse cursors location

Private Sub Form1_Click () Handles Me.Click
    Dim R As Long = GetCursorPos(mousepos) ' You'll get your location in mousepos
    ListBox1.Items.Add(mousepos.X & "x" & mousepos.Y)
End Sub
```

## Explanation

Actually this needs no explanation! It will add both in separate listboxes. The second one will do it for you in only 1 listbox.

And as per your question if you want to save just 10 co-ordinates, you can try the following:

```
Private Sub Form1_Click () Handles Me.Click

    ' This is to be added
    If ListBox1.Items.Count = 10 Then
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    End If
    'till here

    Me.Cursor = New Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle)
    ListBox1.Items.Add(Cursor.Position.X & "x" & Cursor.Position.Y)
End Sub
```

Hope it works perfectly!

Comment: May I ask why import `GetCursorPos`? Just use `Control.MousePosition`.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå, yes I know. Better use the simple one. I gave OP all my knowledge on this topic. Now, it's his/her wish to choose whichever he is comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i finally did:

Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1

```
'  Private Sub Form1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
' Me.Cursor = New Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle)

' Listbox1.Items.Add(Cursor.Position.X)
' Listbox2.Items.Add(Cursor.Position.Y)
' This is to be added
' If ListBox1.Items.Count = 10 Then
'ListBox1.Items.Clear()
' End If
'till here

'   Me.Cursor = New Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle)
' ListBox1.Items.Add(Cursor.Position.X & "x" & Cursor.Position.Y)
'End Sub



Public Function RandomNumber() As Integer
    'initialize random number generator
    Dim r As New Random(System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond)

    Return r.Next(1, 100)
End Function



Public Sub New()
    Me.InitializeComponent()
    Me.list = New BindingList(Of ClickInfo)
    Me.list2 = New BindingList(Of ClickInfo)
    Me.ListBox1.DataSource = Me.list
    Me.ListBox2.DataSource = Me.list2
    Me.ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Location"
    Me.ListBox2.DisplayMember = "Cost"
End Sub

Private Sub _MybaseClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Click
    Me.list.Insert(0, New ClickInfo() With {.Location = Me.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition), .Cost = 1234})
    Me.list2.Insert(0, New ClickInfo() With {.Cost = RandomNumber()})
End Sub

Private Class ClickInfo
    Public Property Location() As Point
    Public Property Cost() As Decimal
End Class

Private ReadOnly list As BindingList(Of ClickInfo)
Private ReadOnly list2 As BindingList(Of ClickInfo)
```

End Class

Comment: You don't need two lists. Remove `list2` and just Set the `cost` like this: `Me.list.Insert(0, New ClickInfo() With {.Location = Me.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition), .Cost = RandomNumber()})`

Comment: BTW, if my answer solved your problem, please click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer as others might find it useful;)